# Finding a 3-embedded subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap, semidirect-product

I have the group of order $108$, $$G=(((\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3)\ltimes \mathbb{Z}_3)\ltimes \mathbb{Z}_2) \ltimes \mathbb{Z}_2$$ obtained from an algorithm in GAP, but I need to prove that it has a $3$-embedded subgroup (a subgroup $H\leq G$ such that $p\mid \ \vert H\vert $ and for any $x\in G-H$, $p \nmid\ \vert H\cap {}^xH \vert$ where $^{x}H=xHx^{-1}$). Does anyone have an idea of how to attack it without using GAP algorithms?

If it helps, it's the group with Id $[108,17]$.

Comment: Since this group has a normal Sylow $3$-subgroup, it can't possibly have a $3$-embedded subgroup.

Comment: You can just take $H=G$. You wrote $H \le G$, so that definitely fits your description!

Comment: The OP was probably hasty when writing the definition of a (strongly) $p$-embedded subgroup. I think the usual definition is: A proper subgroup $H$ of a finite group $G$ is called strongly $p$-embedded if $p$ divides $|H|$ but $p$ does not divide $|H \cap xHx^{-1}|$ for any $x \in G \setminus H$.

Comment: In that case you are correct in saying that it has no strongly $3$-embedded subgroup!